Unity/Vuforia upload target image and overlay video issues
Hello i am current trying to save and upload a chosen target image and overlay video to vuforia but i am getting errors that i cant figure out here is the methods i use and the errors i get below. Also took out access keys.
  async void OnSaveButtonClicked()
{
    string title = titleInputField.text;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(title))
    {
        Debug.LogError("Title cannot be empty.");
        return;
    }

    if (videoRenderTexture == null)
    {
        Debug.LogError("RenderTexture is null.");
        return;
    }

    Texture2D overlayTexture = GetTextureFromUIImage(overlayImageDisplay);

    try
    {
        await UploadImageToFirebase(overlayTexture);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(capturedImageUrl))
        {
            Debug.LogError("Captured image URL is not set.");
            return;
        }

    
        await UploadImageToVuforia(overlayTexture);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedVideoPath))
        {
            await UploadVideoToFirebase(selectedVideoPath);
        }

        string key = databaseReference.Push().Key;
        currentARExperienceData = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "title", title },
        { "capturedImageUrl", capturedImageUrl },
        { "overlayUrl", overlayUrl }
    };


        Debug.Log("Attempting to save data to Firebase...");
        await databaseReference.Child(key).UpdateChildrenAsync(currentARExperienceData);
        Debug.Log("Data saved successfully.");


        Debug.Log("AR experience saved successfully.");
        panelSwitcher.OpenPanel("ProfilePanel");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Failed to save AR experience: " + e.Message);
    }
}

private async Task UploadImageToVuforia(Texture2D image)
{
byte[] imageBytes = EncodeTextureToJPG(image);
    string targetName = "MyTarget";
    string accessKey = "";
    string secretKey = "";
    string endpoint = "https://vws.vuforia.com";

    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, $"{endpoint}/targets")
    {
        Content = new MultipartFormDataContent
        {
            { new ByteArrayContent(imageBytes), "file", "image.jpg" },
            { new StringContent(targetName), "name" }
        }
    };

    string date = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("r");
    string stringToSign = $"{request.Method}\n\n\n{imageBytes.Length}\n{date}\n/targets";
    string signature = GenerateSignature(stringToSign, secretKey);

    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"VWS {accessKey}:{signature}");
    request.Headers.Add("Date", date);

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    try
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
        string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); 

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Debug.Log("Image successfully uploaded to Vuforia!");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError($"Vuforia upload failed: {response.ReasonPhrase}");
            Debug.LogError("Response body: " + responseBody); 
        }
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Vuforia upload failed: " + e.Message);
    }
}

private string GenerateSignature(string stringToSign, string secretKey)
{
    var encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
    byte[] keyBytes = encoding.GetBytes(secretKey);
    byte[] messageBytes = encoding.GetBytes(stringToSign);
    using (var hmacsha1 = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1(keyBytes))
    {
        byte[] hashmessage = hmacsha1.ComputeHash(messageBytes);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(hashmessage);
    }
}

}upload failed: Unauthorized
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)
CreateARManager/d__37:MoveNext () (at Assets/Scripts/CreateARManager.cs:366)
UnityEngine.UnitySynchronizationContext:ExecuteTasks ()
Response body: {"result_code":"AuthenticationFailure","transaction_id":"e58338366f80453fa91d67fbc0f6baf8"}
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)
CreateARManager/d__37:MoveNext () (at Assets/Scripts/CreateARManager.cs:367)
UnityEngine.UnitySynchronizationContext:ExecuteTasks ()
Failed to save AR experience: The method or operation is not implemented.
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)
CreateARManager/d__33:MoveNext () (at Assets/Scripts/CreateARManager.cs:257)
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1:SetResult (int)
Firebase.FutureVoid/<>c__DisplayClass4_0:b__0 () (at /home/runner/work/firebase-unity-sdk/firebase-unity-sdk/linux_unity/app/swig/Firebase.App_fixed.cs:1368)
Firebase.FutureVoid:SWIG_CompletionDispatcher (int) (at /home/runner/work/firebase-unity-sdk/firebase-unity-sdk/linux_unity/app/swig/Firebase.App_fixed.cs:1456)
Firebase.AppUtil:PollCallbacks () (at /home/runner/work/firebase-unity-sdk/firebase-unity-sdk/linux_unity/app/swig/Firebase.App_fixed.cs:4656)
Firebase.Platform.FirebaseAppUtils:PollCallbacks () (at /home/runner/work/firebase-unity-sdk/firebase-unity-sdk/app/platform/FirebaseAppUtils.cs:33)
Firebase.Platform.FirebaseHandler:Update () (at /home/runner/work/firebase-unity-sdk/firebase-unity-sdk/app/platform/Unity/FirebaseHandler.cs:208)
Firebase.Platform.FirebaseMonoBehaviour:Update () (at /home/runner/work/firebase-unity-sdk/firebase-unity-sdk/app/platform/Unity/FirebaseMonoBehaviour.cs:45)
Ive tried using different methods, checked access keys were correct and made sure i was using server keys. Checked end point was correct.

Check the format of your StringToSign to make it conform to the specification:

To encode the Shared Key signature string for a request against the
2009-09-19 version and later of the Blob or Queue service, and version
2014-02-14 and later of the File service, use the following format:

StringToSign = VERB + "\n" +  

               Content-Encoding + "\n" +  

               Content-Language + "\n" +  

               Content-Length + "\n" +  

               Content-MD5 + "\n" +  

               Content-Type + "\n" +  

               Date + "\n" +  

               If-Modified-Since + "\n" +  

               If-Match + "\n" +  

               If-None-Match + "\n" +  

               If-Unmodified-Since + "\n" +  

               Range + "\n" +  

               CanonicalizedHeaders +  

               CanonicalizedResource;

